# Hyperledger Fabric 2.0, where is Fab Token source code?

Tags: token, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, smartcontracts

Can anyone help me to find **FabToken source code** of Hyperledger Fabric? And an example of **Smart contract** that use it?

I've already check a lot of links, for example:

https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/tutorial-fabtoken.html

https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/c/fabric/+/32979

but they don't works.

Thanks

**FINAL UPDATE (for other users)**

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/v2.0.0-alpha/token

**this is the code of FabToken**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, even though Fabtoken was included in the v2.0 alpha version, it was decided to be git-reverted and therefore Fabric v2.0 will not come with the Fabtoken feature.

Comment: I hope that someone have the source code of the alpha version before the removal of Fabtoken feature

Comment: i found this https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/v2.0.0-alpha/token but i don't know if is the FabToken or simply a token

Comment: That is the FabToken source code, as part of the Fabric peer and orderer. However, you cannot use this with current versions